# How can I make a process of a program?

Tags: c, process, fork, execvp

Hey I have to write a small process launcher for uni.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pid_t pid;


    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(pid == 0){
        if(execvp(*argv, argv) < 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my program. I want to call it like ./process-launcher firefox --browser to start a new firefox process.

I think when I start the programm like this there should be a process of firefox in my system monitoring but it isn't

How do I get this?

Compiling with:

clang -o process-launcher process-launcher.c

Comment: And what is the problem you have with your current program you show?

Comment: I can not see the process in my system

Comment: @JanWolfram please [edit] your question and put _all_ relevant information _there_.

Comment: Have you tried using `firefox --browser` directly from terminal? Does it work as intended?

Comment: Yeah directly from terminal it opens firefox. I think you start childprocess and replace the process image to firefox via execvp

Comment: I can't make an answer out of this, because I'm in Windows enveironment and I can't try it, but I can say you are misusing `argv`. It is an array of strings, and its first element is the current program. So, basically, you are executing again your launcher. Forever.

Comment: @Cubo78 haha that worked for me. I changed *argv to argv[1] thx man :)

Answer (score 1):

What is in `*argv`? Your launcher name...

So when executing your code as is, you only relaunch your launcher...

Solution:  `++argv;`, it will pass the second parameter to `execvp`:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pid_t pid;

    if((pid = fork()) < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(pid == 0){

        ++argv;

        printf("execvp(%s, ...)\n", *argv);
        if(execvp(*argv, argv) < 0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx but I have one question left. Will it also execute it with the parameters after the name of the programm like '--browser'

Comment: Yes, this is the point of `++argv;`: At program startup, `argv` is `["./launcher", "firefox", "--browser"]`and after the `++argv;`, is becomes `["firefox", "--browser"]`

Comment: You can try with simpler command like `echo`: try `./launcher echo hello`